# How to make unique ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, variables, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make each `test`(ng-model) like `test1`, `test2` unique in below code..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Array">
  <div>{{item.Name}}</div>
  <a ng-click="openClose(test)>show/hide</a>
  <div ng-show="test">{{item.Des}}</div>
</div>

$scope.openClose = function (modalName) {
  $scope[modalName] = $scope[modalName] ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, we can't understand your requirements. Please write down carefully what you want to achieve. Thank you

Comment: Did you check the answer? Was it helpful?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it was really helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the `show / hide` using the `$index` value you get for each element when you use `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   
    $scope.Array = [{Name:'abc'},{Name:'zzz'},{Name:'yyy'},{Name:'xxx'}];
    
    $scope.openClose = function (index) {
      if($scope.selectedValue == index){
        $scope.selectedValue = -1;
      }else{
        $scope.selectedValue = index;
      }
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
   <div ng-repeat="item in Array">
     <div>{{item.Name}}</div>
      <a ng-click="openClose($index)">show/hide</a>
     <div ng-show='$index === selectedValue'>Hide Show content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```